# CSS Linear Gradient not showing up in Chrome, Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

I'm loading up a CSS file in my Html like so:

```
<head>
<title>H e a d s p a c e</title>
<style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type = "text/css">

        </style>
        </head>
```

whereas my css file looks as follows:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  background: #11e8bb; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #11e8bb, #8200c9); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#11e8bb), to(#8200c9));   
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #11e8bb,#8200c9); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #11e8bb ,#8200c9); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#11e8bb', endColorstr='#8200c9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

However it doesn't actually display anything. The background simply comes through as white. After countless views of other stackoverflow's/online forums I'm helpless - any ideas as to what's wrong?

Both files are on a server and in the same directory. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: CSS looks good. Can you post your folders structure?

Comment: I just have the index.html file and the styles.css both on my server within the same public_html folder.
I'm starting to wonder if it's the three.js code within my html, though I did set  my renderer up appropriately..  `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
   renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);` So I'm super lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your links to style sheets inside a style tag.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type = "text/css">
</head>
```

Is how it should be.
Your code otherwise works just fine.